# Is Apache2 (HTTPD) Location tag a wildcard match?

Tags: apache2, apache

Good news is that I've already solved my problem, bad news is I don't understand the issue!

```
URL: http://host:port/a/b
```

httpd.conf

```
<Location /a>
 ProxyPass to Server....
</Location>

<Location /b>
 ProxyPass to some other Server
</Location>
```

In this setup, my request for `http://.../a/b` takes me to "some other server" instead of the expected "server"

I was able to get my expected behavior by forcing more "regex-y" behavior, and using the starts with expression (aka:

```
<Location ~ "^/a">
 ProxyPass to Server....
</Location>
```

If that's how I have to do it, that's fine.  But the docs seemed rather unclear on this situation.

Documentation Sources:
The Httpd docs on the Location Tag http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#location seem to imply that Location matching in a non-regex manner (aka, no ~) does not use wildcards (that's why they have a section explaining how to use wildcards and regexs).  Also the slash discussion at the end doesn't imply that it uses wildcards either.

So, I'm left to assume that I've uncovered some bug in my version of Apache.  Or maybe I just use too similar of URL structures and can't understand the Apache docs.  Help me, StackOverflow!

Comment: Note: If I switched the order of Locations A and B, this behavior was reversed. So HTTPD was clearly going to the last match found (regardless of best match is what I expected).

Comment: So I guess the answer is no? Can you respond to it and mark it as answered. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you refer to the [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location), it clearly states that

> Regular expressions can also be used, with the addition of the ~
> character. For example:
>
> `<Location ~ "/(extra|special)/data">`
>
> would match URLs that contained
> the substring /extra/data or /special/data.

Comment: ... and uses wildcards otherwise.

Comment: As you can see in my example, I've specified no wildcards.

I would think the rule that would apply is: 
"The specified location, with the addition of a trailing slash, is a prefix of the path component of the URL (also treated as a context root). "

 in this situation, /a/b would NEVER have /b as the context root, and should not match this rule (but did).